# Access local file on Windows 10 with C#.NET application from any user

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-10

I have a desktop application written in C#.NET.  It is running on several computers in different buildings.  Each building has a 3 digit location number.  I want to grab that 3 digit number in the programming of the application.  I want it to be accessible no matter who is logged into the computer.  This is Windows 10 and I tried sticking a text file on the root of the C: drive and got permissions errors.  I thought about maybe setting the location number based on IP address, but I know that can change and things would get ugly fast.  Can someone help me figure out the best way to go about this?

Comment: are you the admin of the machine?

Comment: The "CommonApplicationData" folder (or a subdirectory thereof) as given in the [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) could be a good place to locate the file.

Comment: I am the admin of my machine that I am testing this on.  But I cannot guarantee that the user running the app will be admin.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just grab the name of the machine from System.Environment.MachineName ? (Assuming there is a mapping between the machine name and the location it is in)

Comment: This is a good idea, but I don't know the names of the PC's and I don't feel like going around changing them.